# bower install ECONFLICT unable to find suitable version for angular-bootstrap

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, ui-select

when I run command 'bower install angular-ui-select' it gives me the error  ECONFLICT unable to find suitable version for angular-bootstrap. my bower.json is as follows. my bower.json is as follows.

```
{
  "name": "Analytics Tool",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "authors": [
    "Janith Widarshana"
  ],
  "license": "IOS",
  "homepage": "",
  "ignore": [
    "**/.*",
    "node_modules",
    "public/libs"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "jquery": "~2.1.x",
    "jquery-ui": "~1.11.x",
    "jquery-custom-scrollbar": "0.5.x",
    "bootstrap": "~3.3.*",
    "angular": "~1.4.*",
    "angular-resource": "~1.4.*",
    "angular-animate": "~1.4.*",
    "angular-mocks": "~1.4.*",
    "angular-bootstrap": "~2.1.*",
    "angular-ui-utils": "~3.0.*",
    "angular-ui-router": "~0.2.*",
    "fontawesome": "~4.5.*",
    "ngInfiniteScroll": "~1.2.*",
    "angular-sanitize": "~1.4.*",
    "underscore": "~1.8.3",
    "angular-local-storage": "~0.2.x",
    "flexslider": "~2.6.x",
    "angular-google-maps": "^2.3.2",
    "angular-file-upload": "^2.2.0",
    "ng-table": "^0.8.3",
    "iCheck": "icheck#^1.0.2",
    "bootstrap3-dialog": "bootstrap-dialog#^1.35.1",
    "angular-moment": "^0.10.3",
    "angular-underscore-module": "^1.0.3",
    "isteven-angular-multiselect": "~4.0.0",
    "angular-ui-grid": "^3.1.1",
    "crypto-js": "^3.1.6",
    "angular-bootstrap-colorpicker": "^3.0.25"

  }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45861497/2393789